# Declare a jagged array, consists of one dimentional and two dimentional arrays?

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

Can we declare a jagged array in which some are one dimensional and some are two or multi dimensional arrays. What could be the suggestions.

```
int[][,] jaggedArray1 = new int[3][,] 
{
    new int[,],
    new int[,],
    new int[,] 
};

int[][]  = new int[3][]
{
    new int[],
    new int[],
    new int[]
};
```

**Could we make one array out of these both?**

> EXAMPLE

I am giving here the most suitable example of SUDOKU. :)

Suppose we have 2-D array of strings (say grid), divided into sub-grids.
I am showing a little data.

A GRID OF 4x4. divided into 4 sub-grids. each element is a string enclosed in " "

```
"1,3,", "2,3"        "1,3,", "2,3"
"1,4,", "4,1"        "1,3,", "2,3"

"1,3,", "2,3"        "1,3,", "2,3"
"1,4,", "4,1"        "1,3,", "2,3"
```

If remove "1," from 1st row, 1st col and 1st region. How can we keep track or maintain LOG of the rows that has been changed, cols that has been changed and the each string value that has been changed.

Give suggestions keeping in mind with the lowest SPACE COMPLEXITY.

As we can't make the another duplicate 2-D array as there will be a lot of space which would be wasted.

In my opinion i would need 3 arrays.

ONE Dimentional array will keep record of Rows CHANGED
ONE Dimentional array will keep record of COLS CHANGED
TWO Dimentional array will keep record of CELL VALUE CHANGED

If we transform all these three arrays into one. Work will be alot easier.

I hope i explained the scenario. as i tried my best :D.

Comment: No; that's not possible. And, that sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I agree, you are absolutely right. we could do with this predefined rules of Jagged arrays, but could we make our own type of jagged array mean in our custom data type ...  Frankly speaking ... any open suggestion.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ok I am editing this question with brief example.

Comment: @SLaks please put your smart thinking over question again.

Answer (score 1):

> No; that's not possible.

Sure it is possible.  You just forgot to pin down the array sizes in the initializer, you cannot postpone that forever. Arbitrarily favoring the number 3, this will compile just fine:

```
int[][,] partiallyJaggedArray = new int[3][,] {
    new int[3, 3],
    new int[3, 3],
    new int[3, 3] 
};

int[][] reallyJaggedArray = new int[3][] {
    new int[3],
    new int[3],
    new int[3]
};
```

But with neither of them being a particularly good model for the Sudoku grid.  Picking the right model is 50% of the battle, be sure to pick a good one.

Comment: You can't make an array that can contain both 1D and 2D arrays.

Comment: Not sure we are talking about the same thing.  A declaration like int[][,] is certainly valid, an array that contains a 1D array of 2D array elements.  Try it.

Comment: I am making sense of it. Actually the original problem is Time tabling scheduling using CSP (constraints satisfying problems). But the analogy of sudoku is the closest one to the original one. As far i've created a jagges array.. which is reducing the space complexity by 25-30%.  obj[4][] = {new obj[3], new obj[3], new obj[3], new obj[3]}; Have you any better suggestions....???

Comment: @HansPassant: It looks like I misunderstood the question.  I thought he wanted some elements to be `int[]` and some to be `int[,]`.